# If $x_1 = 3$, $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_n}$ for $n \geq 1$, prove the sequence is bounded below by $0$, above by $4$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

If $x_1 = 3$, $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{4-x_n}$ for $n \geq 1$, prove the sequence is decreasing and bounded below by $0$, above by $4$.

Want to show: $0 < x_{n+1} < x_n < 4$

I decided to do the bounded part first.

---

**Base Case**, $n=1$

$0 < 3 < 4$ [works]

**IH**

Suppose $0 < x_k < 4$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$

**IS**

Show $0 < x_{k+1} < 4$

We know $x_{k+1} = \dfrac{1}{4-x_k}$

We also know that $0 < x_k < 4$, by **IH**.

So we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{4} < x_{k+1} < \infty$$

But this doesn't show the boundness. Where have I went wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's better to prove that $0<x_k\leq3$ then you have that $4$ is trivially a upper bound.

Comment: Hmmm It's directly asked from the question, so I don't think I can change it

Comment: If $x_k\leq 3$ then $x_k\leq 3<4$ which is what you want to prove.

Comment: If I did that, then I would have
$$0 < x_k \leq 3$$
$$0 > -x_k \geq -3$$
$$4 > 4-x_k \geq 1$$
$$\dfrac{1}{4} < \dfrac{1}{4-x_k}\leq 1$$

From this can I conclude that we are bounded above by $4$, below by $0$?

Comment: Yup, looks fine.  :)

Comment: May be when you prove lower bound $0$ ; $$\frac{1}{4-x_n} > 0 \implies 4-x_n>0 \implies x_n<4$$

Comment: exercise 2.4.1 in the book Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957023/convergence-of-the-recursive-sequence-x-n1-frac14-x-n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove recursively defined sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734044/prove-recursively-defined-sequence-converges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extension of the problem**

As a bonus we can also find the explicit solution of the recursion

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_n}, \,\,x_1 = 3$$

Letting

$$x_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$$

and comparing numerators and denominators we get a system of two linear recursions

$$p_{n+1} = q_n\tag {1} $$
$$q_{n+1} = 4 q_n - p_n\tag {2}$$

We can eliminate the variable $q_n$ by shifting the index in $(1)$ one unit, and then using $(2)$ which leads to

$$p_{n+2} = q_{n+1} = 4 q_n - p_n$$

now replacing $q_n$ by $(1)$ we find finally a recursion in $p_n$ only:

$$p_{n+2} = 4 p_{n+1} - p_n\tag{3}$$

The initial values can be taken as

$$p_1 = 3, p_2 = 1$$

The original variable is then given by

$$x_n = \frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}\tag{4}$$

(I believe the reader can take it from here, so I pause for a while before giving the solution.)

**Solution**

The recursion can be solved assuming that

$$p_n = \lambda^n$$

Inserting this into $(3)$ leads to the characteristic equation

$$\lambda^2 = 4 \lambda -1$$

Notice that we obtain this equation also if we seek solutions $p$ which are independent of $n$.

The solutions are

$$\lambda_{+}=2+\sqrt 3\simeq 3.732050807568877\tag{5a}$$
$$\lambda_{-}=2-\sqrt 3\simeq 0.2679491924311228\tag{5b}$$

The general solution is then

$$p_n = A \lambda_{+}^n + B  \lambda_{-}^n$$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants to be determined by the intial conditions.

In our case the compete solution is

$$p_n = \frac{1}{6} \left(\left(33+19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _-^n+\left(33-19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _+^n\right)\tag {6}$$

The first $10$ values are

$$p_{1..10} = (3,1,1,3,11,41,153,571,2131,7953)$$

This sequence can be found in https://oeis.org/ under the ID $A001835 \;a(n) = 4*a(n-1) - a(n-2)$, with $a(0)=1, a(1)=1.$

The original variable $x$ is then, according to $(4)$ given by

$$x_n=\frac{\left(33+19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _-^n+\left(33-19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _+^n}{\left(33+19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _-^{n+1}+\left(33-19 \sqrt{3}\right) \lambda _+^{n+1}}\tag {7}$$

It is interesting to extend the sequence to negative values of $n$. Between $-5$ and $+10$ we find

$$x_{(-5)..10}=\left\{\frac{7953}{2131},\frac{2131}{571},\frac{571}{153},\frac{153}{41},\frac{41}{11},\frac{11}{3},3,1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{11},\frac{11}{41},\frac{41}{153},\frac{153}{571},\frac{571}{2131},\frac{2131}{7953},\frac{7953}{29681}\right\}$$

The graph is

[image]

We see that the limiting values for large positive and negative $n$ are the eigenvalues. This can also easily be derived from $(7)$.

Furthermore, all values are between $0$ and $4$. This proves the original assertion even if extended to all $n$.

**Generalisation**

The same method can be used to solve the more general recursion

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{a\; x_n + b}{c\; x_n + d}\tag {8}$$

where $a, b, c, d$ are constant coefficients.

An alternative method starts from the following procedure: calculate $x_{n+2}$ in terms of $x_n$, recognize the same form of the recursion with new coefficients, and find the rule by which the new coefficients are formed.

EDIT 15.04.17: Here is a reference in which this method is discussed extensiveley under the heading of "linear fractionl transformations": http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath464/kmath464.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $x_1=3,x_2=1,x_3=\frac{1}{3},x_4=\frac{3}{11},x_5=\frac{11}{41},...,x_n=\frac{p}{q},x_{n+1}=\frac{q}{4q-p}$

If
$$x_n=\frac{p}{q}<1 \Rightarrow p<3q \Rightarrow q + p < 4q$$ 
$$\Rightarrow 0 < q < 4q-p  \Rightarrow 0<\frac{q}{4q-p}=x_{n+1}<1$$
and applying induction starting with $x_3$ leads to $0<x_n<1,n\geq3$.

Also, function $f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x}$ [is increasing (since $f'(x)>0$)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(4-x)) and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ thus: $$x_n>x_{n+1} \Rightarrow f(x_n)>f(x_{n+1}) \Rightarrow x_{n+1} > x_{n+2}$$

Comment: How did you get $p/q < 1$

Comment: @KSplitX I updated my answer ...