# Abbott Exercise: Prove that $ x_1 = 3 $, $ x_{n+1} = \frac {1} {4-x_n} $ converges.

Tags: analysis, induction

In *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott
there is an exercise:
$$\text{Prove that $ x_1 = 3 $, $ x_{n+1} = \frac {1} {4-x_n} $ converges}$$

In the solution Abbott says that the series is bounded by the following logic:

- Need to prove that if $ x_n > x_{n+1} $, then $ x_{n+1} > x_{n+2} $.
- $x_n > x_{n+1} $ implies that $ −x_n <−x_{n+1} $. Then we have $ 4−x_n <4−x_{n+1} $.

The conclusion of the above is that $x_n$ is decreasing.

I can follow. But how can one just assume $x_n > x_{n+1}$ by only the first and second term? I feel somewhat uncomfortable with this, as in it's not a complete proof, why is this ok?

I mean he used $ x_n > x_{n+1} $ as a fact and base, though it was something that is needed to be proven to show that the sequence is bounded no?

Thank you, I'm probably asking silly obvious things again.

Comment: It's called mathematical induction. See here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/induction/

Comment: @Atticus Thanks, I see the inductive step now, it's a little different from what I was used to but it's actually quite clear. So embarrassed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858698/prove-that-x-n1-frac14-x-n-converges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in a comment, this is just an induction step to show that the sequence is decreasing.

But if this is all what is written, it is definitely not a complete proof of the convergence of the sequence.

A possible way to see the boundedness of the sequence you may argue in a similar way as in the book:

- For $0\leq x\leq 3 \Rightarrow 0\geq -x\geq -3 \Rightarrow 4 \geq 4-x \geq 1 \Rightarrow \boxed{\frac 14 \leq \frac 1{4-x}\leq 1}$

So, boundedness is established.

For monotonicity you can just invoke the derivative of $f(x)=\frac 1{4-x}$:

- $\boxed{f'(x)= -\frac{1}{(4-x)^2} < 0}$ on $[0,3]$. So, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

Now, since $x_2 <x_1=3$, you can conclude using strict monotonicity and induction that

$$x_{n+1}=f^{n-1}(x_2) < f^{n-1}(x_1)=x_n \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N},$$

where $f^{n-1}$ denotes the $(n-1)$-fold composition of $f$.

Comment: Hi @trancelocation thank you! Your way is more or less how I did it. 
I understand induction, I just feel like that he skipped over showing the inductive step holds? 
It feels to me it's more like an assumption that n+1 holds as well without proving it. Is that also what you feel is missing? If yes, that would make me very relieved.
I mean there is no ratio or pattern (it's kind of nested), and without further manipulation (like guessing >=) I feel it's incomplete. thanks again.

Comment: Apologies, I see the inductive step now, it's quite obvious and I was pretty ignorant to it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @oliver : You are welcome. No need for apologies. That's quite normal that we do not see the obvious once in a while. Happens to me as well once in a while. :-)

Comment: It was a multiduplicate. No need to (re)write such a proof.